# datatable .net 2.0 select with double single quote returns no results

Tags: c#, .net, select, datatable, single-quotes

I've datatable as follows

```
DataTable ex= new DataTable();
ex.Columns.Add("Object");
ex.Columns.Add("Found");

ex.Rows.Add("vase''s","True");

string keyword="vase''s";

DataRow [] drs = ex.Select("[Object] like '%" + keyword + "%'");
```

drs is always empty I've tried with equal I've the same results and I've tested in other frameworks I've the same also 
what's wrong in my select statement ?!

**Update**
I realized that it's due to single quote is considered as one in the query statement but how can I do that search in a generic way

Comment: `keyword.Replace("'", "''")` ?

Comment: are there anyway as I don't want to call replace function if there's no single quotes it cost me a check

Comment: It will cost more to perform that check than to replace it anyways

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to be like below

```
        DataTable ex = new DataTable();
        ex.Columns.Add("Object");
        ex.Columns.Add("Found");

        ex.Rows.Add("vase's", "True"); //don't escape here

        string keyword = "vase''s";
        //Use a equal to comparison rather than using LIKE operator
        DataRow[] drs = ex.Select("[Object] = '" + keyword + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The string value in your table literally has two single quotes.  You do not escape single quotes in C# strings.  The `Select` statement just needs two single quotes to tell the parser that the quote is not the end of the constant string value.  So either keep a single quote in the value:

```
ex.Rows.Add("vase's", "True");
```

or search for a string with two single quotes:

```
string keyword = "vase''''s";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you added that `DataRow`, you're informed the `vase''s` value (with two single quotes) and you (probably) don't want it.

However you MUST escape it in the query, like below:

```
DataTable ex = new DataTable();
ex.Columns.Add("Object");
ex.Columns.Add("Found");
ex.Rows.Add("vase's", "True");

foreach (DataRow row in ex.Rows)
    Console.WriteLine(row["Object"]);   // "vase's"

string keyword = "vase's";
DataRow[] drs = ex.Select("[Object] like '%" + keyword.Replace("'", "''") + "%'");
Console.WriteLine("{0} rows found", drs.Length);
```